# jQuery AJAX Loading Page Content Only After I Press Shift Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax + jquery loading page only after holding shift key and duplicate new empty window.
If I press the loading button nothing hapen, only after I press shift key I get to load the page correctly...

this is my ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".getUsersA").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".gridD").html(spinner)
            },
            url: 'lib/some_url.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({
                data1:'2013-09-01'
                }),
            success: function  (results) 
                {$(".gridD").html(results);}
        });
    });
});
```

I have a second js file with just this line of code for spinner

```
var spinner = "<img src='images/spinner.gif' border='0'>";
```

html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Putting it all tugether ... with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="thedivD"><a href="" class="buttonA getUsersA">Get Users</a></div>

    <h3>jQuery results</h3>
    <div class="gridD"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you pos your html code to? the script does not cointain anything I would consider incorrect

Comment: What do you mean by "loading button"? Is it ".getUsersA" button, or "F5" key, or what? Your HTML would be *very* useful...

Comment: The console does not receive any error.

Comment: MarcoS, I said button "figuratively"

Comment: You say your ajax never success ?

Comment: Maybe your computer is just incredibly slow. :D

Comment: What you want to correct here ?

Comment: The problem is that if I press the "button" to get data from php, nothing happens.
But if I hold down the SHIFT key, I generate the content of the file .php but I opened again and a second empty window

Comment: what is the relation with shift key in your code ?

Comment: I have no realtion with shift key ... the weird part is that my code work only if you press the Shift key. I ask here because I do not understand why it happens this strangeness.

Comment: Have you tried change '(' to '['

Comment: I make the change but I recive error (SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 

}],

 
)

Comment: Sorry, which OS/browser are you using?

Comment: firefox / chrome - windows7

Comment: I can't fully reproduce your code because I miss "js/general.js" and the html for "spinner". I suppose the JS you did provide is the content of "js/ajax.js", is it correct?

Comment: general js contein only this line of code for spinner #var spinner = "<img src='images/spinner.gif' border='0'>";#

Comment: O.k. Are you sure 'lib/some_url.php' is valid and return the data you expect?

Comment: that's what driving me crazy in jquery
If access some_url.php separately I get all the date I need
If access ".gridD"  by pressing the shift key I get all the date I need

only if the access ".gridD"  normally do not get anything, not even an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
<a href="" ...
```

to

```
<a href="#" ...
```

in your HTML... a blank href is a link to this same url, so a click on the button forces also a page reload...

Comment: For three days I'm looking on the internet for a solution and I found nothing. 
Thanks a lot for your time and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: [{
                data1:'2013-09-01'
                }]
```

try It.

If you can not post the data1 or success not coming.

```
$.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".gridD").html(spinner)
            },
            url: 'lib/some_url.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: [{
                "data1":'2013-09-01'
                }],
            success: function  (results) 
                {$(".gridD").html(results);}
        });
```

?

Comment: does not help, i change with this #data: [{ data1:'2013-09-01' }],# and I recive thie error #SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 

}],

 
#